# creación y llamado de funciones en C++

Tags: c++, funcion

La idea es que la función debe crear una matriz lo cual el código  en un main() en forma independiente lo hace. Sin embargo, cuando lo quiero convertir en una función me están surgiendo los siguientes mensaje de error:

codigoAfuncion.cpp|17|error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int (*)[4]' [-fpermissive]|
codigoAfuncion.cpp|24|error: declaration of 'int matriz [4][4]' shadows a parameter|

El código:

'''

```
#include<iostream>
   #include<stdio.h>
   #include<conio.h>
   #include<stdlib.h>
   using namespace std;

   //prototipo de las funciones
   void crearmatriz(int matriz[4][4], int fila, int columna);



   int main()
   {
     int matriz[4][4];
     int fila;
     int columna;
     crearmatriz(matriz[4][4], fila, columna);

   }


   void crearmatriz(int matriz[4][4], int fila, int columna)
   {
       int matriz[4][4];
       printf("\n\t************************************");
       printf("\n\t Ingrese los elementos de la matriz:");
       printf("\n");
       for(int fila=0;fila<4;fila++)
          {for(int columna=0;columna<4;columna++)
              {
                  printf("\tDe la fila #%d, de la columna #%d: ",fila+1,columna+1);
                  scanf("%d",&matriz[fila][columna]);
              }//fin 1er. for anidado
          }//fin 1er. for
          printf("\n");

      //se muestra la matriz en pantalla
      printf("\n\t La matriz ingresada es:");
      printf("\n");
      for(int fila=0;fila<4;fila++)
         {for(int columna=0;columna<4;columna++)
             {
                printf("\t");
                printf("%d",matriz[fila][columna]);
             }//fin 2o. for anidado
      printf("\n");
        }//fin 2o. for

}
```

'''

Answer (score 1):

El primer error se produce porque le pasas un elemento de la matriz a la función `crearmatriz` cuando se supone que le pases la matriz completa:

```
int matriz[4][4];
int fila, columna;
crearmatriz(matriz[4][4], fila, columna); // <--- Aquí está el error
```

Corrección:

```
crearmatriz(matriz, fila, columna);
```

El segundo error porque tienes una variable local llamada igual que el parámetro:

```
void crearmatriz(int matriz[4][4], int fila, int columna)
{
    int matriz[4][4]; // <--- Aquí
    ...
}
```

Corrección:

```
void crearmatriz(int matriz[4][4], int fila, int columna)
{
    ...
}
```

---

Algunas sugerencias:

- No uses la librería `conio.h` porque es exclusiva de Windows. Si solo la quieres para `system("pause")`, puedes lograr un efecto similar con las  siguientes líneas:

  ```
  std::cout << "Presiona una tecla para continuar";
  std::cin.get();
  ```
- Sé consistente. Tienes 2 librerías que hacen lo mismo. `iostream` con funciones de C++ y `stdio.h` de C. Lo mejor es que te quedes solo con `iostream`. De igual manera, no  necesitas `stdlib.h`. C++ tiene sus propias librerías implementando la funcionalidad que encuentras ahí.